# Batch File - Read specific line, and save a specific string in that line as a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there any way to get for /f loop (or anything else) to read a specific line?

Here is the code I have so far, it reads first word of every line.

```
@echo off
set file=readtest.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%A in (%file%) do (echo %%A)
pause
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Additional Information: I want to make a batch file which will rename a TXT file to a string within that TXT file, located at a specific location. I have figured out how to rename files, all I need to learn to do is to retrieve a string (located at a specific location) with in the file which will go into the name of that TXT file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't fully defined what you mean by "a specific location", I'll make some (reasonable, in my opinion) assumptions, though the method I present is equally valid no matter what your definition turns out to be.

You can get arbitrary lines and arbitrary words on that line by using a line counter variable in conjunction with `tokens`.

Let's assume your text file name can be found as the second argument on the fourth line of the `infile.txt` file. You can get that with something like:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set /a "line = 0"
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in (infile.txt) do (
    set /a "line = line + 1"
    if !line!==4 set thing=%%a
)
endlocal & set thing=%thing%
echo %thing%
```

This actually uses a few "tricks" which warrant further explanation:

- the `line` counter to ensure you only grab what you want from a *specific* line, though you could change the test `!line!==4` into anything you need such as a line beginning with `#`, the fifth line containing the string `xyzzy` and so on.
- the use of `setlocal/endlocal` to effectively give you a scope from which variables cannot leak. This is good programming practice even for a language often not normally associated with such things :-)
- the use of `endlocal & set` to *bypass* that scope so that `thing` is the only thing that *does* actually leak (as it should).
- the use of delayed expansion and `!..!` variables to ensure they're correct within the `for` loop. Without this, the `%..%` will always be expand to the value they were set to when the `for` loop started.

Those last two bullet points are actually related. `%..%` variables are expanded when the command is *read* rather than when it is executed.

For a `for` loop, the command is the entire thing from the `for` to the final `)`. That means, if you use `%line%` within the loop, that will be evaluated *before* the loop starts running, which will result in it always being `0` (the variable itself may change but the expansion of it has already happened). However, `!line!` will be evaluated each time it is encountered within the loop so will have the correct value.

Similarly, while `endlocal` would normally clear out all variables created after the `setlocal`, the command:

```
endlocal & set thing=%thing%
```

is a *single* command in the context of expansion. The `%thing%` is expanded *before* `endlocal` is run, meaning it effectively becomes:

```
endlocal & set thing=whatever_thing_was_set_to_before_endlocal
```

That's why the use of `setlocal` and `endlocal & set` is a very useful way to limit variables "escaping" from a scope. And, yes, you can chain multiple `& set` stanzas to allow more variables to escape the scope.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `&&` ("Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB") instead of `&` ("Run commandA and then run commandB")? [reference](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: @Stephan, not really, it would only be an issue if `endlocal` could fail which I don't believe is the case. However, I'd probably prefer to use `&&` so as not to confuse any UNIX bods looking at it, since `&` serves a *vastly* different in UNIX-land and I'm aware of their limited mental capacity [just joking, but I'll duck for cover just in case :-) ].

Comment: I noticed the wide spread false view, that `&&` means "And then do" in batch (instead of correct "And if that was successful, then do"). Although it may not make any differece here, it can make a huge difference in another context. And with a quick glance to your reputation, I better asked, in case I missed something. I can't say anthing about the mental capacity of the unix-guys - we killed all of them a few years ago [also ducking]

Comment: @Stephan, have changed it to better match the intent since, now that I've thought about it, it probably makes more sense - you want `thing` to escape the scope no matter what.